# Angular RxJS - set valueChanges pipe value to null until observable resolved

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to pipe valueChanges from a `select` to fire off the appropriate API request and show a spinner while the response hasn't been received. On top of that I'm trying to use `publish()` and `refCount()` so that I can use that observable with the `async` pipe in multiple places in my template.

**my-component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.results$ = this.selectControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith('hard'),
    switchMap((evalStrategy: 'hard' | 'soft') => this.apiService.getResults(evalStrategy)),
    publish(),
    refCount()
  );
}
```

**my-component.html**

```
<mat-progress-spinner *ngIf="!(results$ | async)"></mat-progress-spinner>

<div *ngIf="results$ | async">
   <p>Name {{(results$ | async).name}}</p>
   <small>{{(results$ | async).description}}
</div>
```

Ideally, I'd expect this code to work and only fire off just **1 request** to the server.

But I end up getting `Cannot read property 'name' of null` :(

If I make the following change to **my-component.html**

```
<mat-progress-spinner *ngIf="!(results$ | async)"></mat-progress-spinner>

<div *ngIf="(results$ | async) as results">
   <p>Name {{(results).name}}</p>
   <small>{{(results).description}}
</div>
```

Then it works fine and the only fire's off 1 request to the server. But when you change the select option, `results$ | async` no longer evaluates to `null` until the new value is available. Instead, it sticks with the old value and then all of a sudden replaces it with the updated one.

Comment: let me get your question right. You expect that: when you change the select option, `results$ | async` should be changed to `null` until the new value is available?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Try with `(results)?.name` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want to separate out the variables - so that context is clearer - status of `loading` and final `results` are two different things. Making an assumption that `results` are `null` equates to `status` is loading can be dangerous, as they are fundamentally different. For example, what happens if there is error? That would mean `results` is null and yet the `status` is no longer loading. If following your implementation your spinner will be forever loading when an error is thrown. And also it could run into the scenario you described - You lose the state of the `loading`, cos now its no longer `null` and your spinner will never loads after the first initial request.

It is also kinda redundant (pointless) to reset your `results` to `null` every time you there is a change in your form. Technically your results are not `null`. It has results. Just that the results are not the latest.

Instead, use a subject to emit values:

```
private isLoading = new BehaviourSubject<boolean>(false);
```

and in your component, simply use `.tap()` to change the status of the `Subject`:

```
this.results$ = this.selectControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith('hard'),
    tap(() => this.isLoading.next(true)), //sets loading to true, we are firing our api request!
    switchMap((evalStrategy: 'hard' | 'soft') => this.apiService.getResults(evalStrategy)),
    tap(() => this.isLoading.next(false)), //api finished fetching, stop the spinner!
    catchError(() => this.isLoading.next(false)), //this is up to you on how you want to do error handling.
    publish(),
    refCount(),
);
```

and get your html to bind to it:

```
<mat-progress-spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-progress-spinner>
```

Comment: `isLoading` can't be private and we should bind to `isLoading|async`. But this doesn't fire off the request at all because the div that uses `results$` will have `*ngIf="!loading"`. So, nobody subscribes to `results$`. I tried using `*ngIf="(results$ | async) && !loading"`, which fires the request but I get the error `Cannot read property 'name' of null` again.

Comment: Agree with your "separation of concerns argument" btw

Comment: "redundant" and "pointless" are not synonyms as you seem to suggest. It's also neither redundant nor pointless to reset a result to null when it's being reloaded, it depends on the requirements.